# Normability of weak $L^p$-spaces

Tags: integration, measure-theory, normed-spaces, lp-spaces, weak-lp-spaces

Let  $(X, \mathcal A,\mu)$ be a measure space, and $0<p<\infty$

> **Definition:** The weak $L^p-$space on $(X, \mathcal A,\mu)$
>   denoted $L^{p,\infty}(X, \mu)$ is defined as the set of all $\mu$-measurable functions $f$ such that: 
>   $$\|f\|_{L^{p,\infty}} = \sup\{ t\mu\left(\{x\in X: |f(x)|>t\}\right)^{1/p}: t>0\}<\infty.$$

One can easily check that the map $f\mapsto \|f\|_{L^{p,\infty}}$ is a quasi norm. namely we have the **quasi-triangular inequality**
$$\|f+g\|_{L^{p,\infty}} \le \max(2,2^{1/p})\left(\|f\|_{L^{p,\infty}}+\|g\|_{L^{p,\infty}}\right)$$

Now we assume is a $\sigma-$finite measure space. Let $0<r<p<\infty $ we define
$$|\|f|\|_{L^{p,\infty}} = \sup_{0<\mu(E)<\infty} \mu(E)^{-\frac1r+\frac1p} \left(\int_E |f|^rd\mu\right)^{1/r}$$
the surpemun is taken over all measurable subsets $E$ of $X$ of finite measure.

> **Question:** prove that $|\|\cdot|\|_{L^{p,\infty}}$ and $\|\cdot\|_{L^{p,\infty}}$ are equivalent. Then conclude that $L^{p,\infty}$ is normable for $p>1$ and metrisable for $0<p\le 1.$

I was able to prove that, $$\|f\|_{L^{p,\infty}}\le |\|f|\|_{L^{p,\infty}}$$ which is easy from the definition. Now How can I prove that

$$|\|f|\|_{L^{p,\infty}}\le c_p \|f\|_{L^{p,\infty}}$$

This would answer the others questions it is not difficult to see that $$f\mapsto  |\|f|\|_{L^{p,\infty}}$$ is a norm for $p>1.$

Comment: Can you please define what you mean by "normability"?  The ability to be Norma?  The ability to be normal?  Only people have the ability to be normal.  In any case, what you highlight as the "question" is not in fact a question.  It is a problem statement demanding a proof and a conclusion.  It's not nice to come here demanding anything.

Comment: Well, I am one, and it's an awesome field to pursue.  I'd really like you to understand the difference between, say "prove that ... xyz....".  and  "I need to prove that ...xyz....  I've done this ...abc..., and I know this ...pqr..., but is it the case that ...kmn...?"   A real-live question, and not merely an imperative.

Comment: @amWhy And topological spaces.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/685034/equivalence-of-norms-on-weak-lp?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It suffices to show that there exists a constant $c$ such that for each $E$ of positive and finite measure, 
$$
\int_E\left\lvert f\right\rvert^r\leqslant c\left\lVert f \right\rVert_{\mathbb L^{p,\infty }   }^p\mu\left(E\right)^{1-p/r}.                
$$
To this aim, use Fubini's thereom to get 
$$
\int_E\left\lvert f\right\rvert^r=\int_{\mathbb R }\mu\left(\left\{    x\mid \left\lvert f(x)\right\rvert^r\mathbf 1_E (x) \gt t \right\}        \right)  \mathrm dt     
$$
and observing that 
$$
\left\{    x\mid \left\lvert f(x)\right\rvert^r\mathbf 1_E (x) \gt t \right\} 
=\left\{    x\mid \left\lvert f(x)\right\rvert^r\gt t \right\} \cap E $$
we derive that 
$$
\int_E\left\lvert f\right\rvert^r\leqslant \int_{\mathbb R }\min\left\{   \mu\left(\left\{    x\mid \left\lvert f(x)\right\rvert^r \gt t \right\}        \right),\mu\left(E\right)   \right\}    \mathrm dt.
$$
Since 
$$\mu\left(\left\{    x\mid \left\lvert f(x)\right\rvert^r \gt t \right\}        \right)=\mu\left(\left\{    x\mid \left\lvert f(x)\right\rvert \gt t^{1/r}     \right\}        \right)\leqslant t^{-p/r}\left\lVert f \right\rVert_{\mathbb L^{p,\infty }   }^p,$$
we are able to conclude.