# Given a CZO, $T$, $\delta \in (0,1)$, and $A_1$ weight $w$, is the map $f \rightarrow M_\delta[T[f]]$ weak (1,1) with respect to $w dx$?

Tags: real-analysis, harmonic-analysis

Here, $$M_\delta[g](x) = \sup_{x \in Q} \left(\frac{1}{|Q|}\int_{Q}g(y)^{\delta}dx\right)^{\frac1\delta}.$$ Let $f^* = M_1[f]$, and denote $w(E) := \int_{E}w(y)dy$. By a CZO, I mean that $T$ is a Calderon-Zygmund Operator,    and so is in particular bounded from $L^p(wdx)$ to $L^p(wdx)$ for all $1<p<\infty$. By $dy$ and $dx$ I mean integration with respect to the Lebesgue measure.

It is clear that for all $f \in L^1(wdx)\cap L^2(wdx)$, that:
$$ w( M_\delta[T[f]] > \lambda) \lesssim \frac{\|f\|_{L^1(wdx)}}{\lambda}.$$
Indeed, if we let $E = \{ M_\delta[T[f]] > \lambda\}$, then $$w(E) < w((Tf)^* > \lambda) \lesssim \frac{ \|T[f]\|_{L^2(wdx)}^2}{\lambda^2} \lesssim \frac{\|f\|_{L^2(wdx)}^2}{\lambda^2} < \infty,$$ so that $E$ has finite measure (with respect to $wdx$) and Komolgorov's inequality is available.

Hence, $w(E) = w([T[f]^\delta]^* > \lambda^\delta) \lesssim \frac{\int_E\|T[f]\|^\delta}{\lambda^\delta} < \lambda^{-\delta}w(E)^{1-\delta}[T[f]]_{L^{1,\infty}(wdx)}^{
\delta} <  \lambda^{-\delta}w(E)^{1-\delta}\|f\|_{L^{1}(wdx)}^{
\delta}$ Rearranging yields $w(E) \lesssim \frac{\|f\|_{L^1(wdx)}}{\lambda}$.

I want to improve this inequality so that it holds for all $f \in L^1(wdx)$ not just $f \in L^1(wdx)\cap L^2(wdx)$. When $w = 1$ this can be done by using the boundedness of $T: H^1 \rightarrow L^1(dx)$. For general $w \in A_1(dx) $ It should also be true, but I fail to see why. Presumably a density argument works, but I can't seem to find it.

Comment: What is a CZO ?

Comment: @JeanMarie very late reply but a CZO (Calderon-Zygmund operator) is a singular integral operator associated to a Calderon-Zygmund kernel (i.e., its kernel satisfies some decay properties) which is in addition bounded between $L^2$ and $L^2$.

Comment: @Pelota Thanks... Never too late to learn something...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an argument that might work: Let $f_n=f*\eta_n$, for some nice approximate identity $(\eta_n)_n$.

Since $Tf_n\to Tf$ in measure, we may assume that $Tf_n\to Tf$ a.e. as well (take a subsequence and label it the same as the original). By Fatou's Lemma and definition of $\sup$, we have that $M_\delta(Tf)\leq \liminf_n M_\delta(Tf_n)$ a.e. Finally, recall that $g$ being $L^{1,\infty}$ is equivalent to $g^\delta\in L^{1/\delta,\infty}$ and
$$
\Vert g\Vert_{L^{1,\infty}} \approx \Vert g^\delta\Vert^{1/\delta}_{L^{1/\delta,\infty}}.
$$

We'll be using a characterization of weak $L^p$ spaces in terms of a 'Hölder inequality for sets', see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2540071/normability-of-weak-lp-spaces) question (set $r=1$ and $p=1/\delta>1$)

Fix a set of finite measure $A$, then using Fatou's Lemma:
\begin{align}
\int_A M([Tf]^\delta) wdx & \leq \int_A \liminf_n M([Tf_n]^\delta) wdx \\ & \leq \liminf_n \int_A M([Tf_n]^\delta) wdx \\ &\leq\liminf_n \Vert M([Tf_n]^\delta)\Vert_{L^{1/\delta,\infty}} w(A)^{1-\delta}\\
& \leq w(A)^{1-\delta}\liminf_n \| M_\delta(Tf_n)\|^\delta_{L^1,\infty}.
\end{align}
This gives that $\Vert M([Tf]^\delta)\Vert_{L^{1/\delta,\infty}}\leq \liminf_n \Vert M_\delta(Tf_n)\|^\delta_{L^{1,\infty}}$, and from here it's easy to conclude using the bound you have.